# Set default values in react-hook-form conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

**Background:**
I have a very long complex form with deep nested objects creating using rhf (`react-hook-form`). I want to provide a checkbox at the top of the form which toggles the default values in the fields to assist the user.

**Problem**
By using rhf, I was able to fill up the `defaultValues` using `reset` method but now the issue is once I call the `reset` method with the `defaultValues`, I can't unset the values using the `reset` if I provide an empty object.

**Things I've tried**
I've tried using the `setValue` method but it unset only 1 field at once and it'll require recursion to set values for deep-nested object.

**Code** 
Here's a very minimal example of what I'm trying to do.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const defaultValues = { name: `John Doe` };

const Form = () => {
  const [useDefaultValues, setUseDefaultValues] = useState(false);
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (useDefaultValues) {
      reset(defaultValues);
    } else {
      reset({}, { keepValues: false, keepDefaultValues: false });
    }
  }, [useDefaultValues]);

  return (
    <>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          value={useDefaultValues}
          onChange={() => setUseDefaultValues((prev) => !prev)}
        />
        Use Default values
      </label>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" {...register("name")} />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Form />, rootElement);
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-hook-form-reset-form-forked-sxmy8q?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A1%2C1-42%2C1

Notice how unsetting the `defaultValues` doesn't empty the form again

Comment: Have you tried this property? "keepDefaultValues" -> Keep the same defaultValues which are initialised via useForm. isDirty will be checked again: it is set to be the result of the comparison of any new values provided against the original defaultValues. dirtyFields will be updated again if values are provided: it is set to be result of the comparison between the new values provided against the original defaultValues.

Comment: It's already being used in the example, check the code

Comment: You should pass default value array instead of {} this.

Answer (score 0):

Your form need to have 3 states. First one containing the `default values`. Second one need to have `empty value` (actual reset). Third one need to have `actual(current) values` which will be handled by react hook form.

**An optional object to reset form values, and it's recommended to provide the entire defaultValues when supplied.** [Source](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/reset)

**The Solution to the your Code:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const defaultValues = { name: `John Doe` }; // your own default values

const Form = () => {
  const [useDefaultValues, setUseDefaultValues] = useState(false);
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm({
    defaultValues: { name: `` },
  }); // actual empty defaul values, you can provide here

  useEffect(() => {
    if (useDefaultValues) {
      reset(defaultValues, { keepValues: false, keepDefaultValues: true }); // reset to defaultValues provided above
    } else {
      reset(); // reset to actual empty defaul values
    }
  }, [useDefaultValues]);

  return (
    <>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          value={useDefaultValues}
          onChange={() => setUseDefaultValues((prev) => !prev)}
        />
        Use Default values
      </label>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" {...register("name")} />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Form />, rootElement);
```

**keepValues(true):**

Form input values will remain unchanged. Let say we changed the `name` to `'abc'` then we call

```
reset(newValues, { keepValues: true });
```

The form will still have the old values. The `newValues` given here would have no effect.

On the other hand, if we have `keepValues(false)` the value will become equal to the `newValues` provided in the reset function otherwise (if empty object provided) it become default values.

**keepDefaultValues(true):**

The form values given in the reset function become the default values. In order to identify any change in the state of the form we use `isDirty`. If we have `keepDefaultValues(true)`, the `isDirty` will compare the default value with the current form value to tell whether the form state has changed or not.

On the other hand, if we have `keepDefaultValues(false)`, the `isDirty` will compare the new given value in the reset function with the current form value to tell whether the form state has changed or not.

In simple words in addition to this use case, the `keepDefaultValues` fucntion can be useful if we want to keep the Default value same as we provided in the beginning by using `keepDefaultValues(true)`.